# Javascript variable to html page 'script tag'

Tags: javascript, html, variables

Is it possible, if one has a javascript variable like this:

```
var myVariable = "alert('BAM! It works!');"
```

to send it to an html page that has a script tag in, in other words, looks like this:
   `<script id="theScriptTag"></script>`

and by 'sending' I mean going like this in the Javascript file:

```
getElementById("theScriptTag").innerHTML = myVariable;
```

Now maybe people normally don't do this. If there's another way to get a Javascript variable to an HTML page please don't hessitate to tell. It's difficult for me to explain **why** I would like to do it like this, only that I **need** to do it like this.

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT...**

From all the comments I can see this is some serious bad practice. Let me give you the over view and 'bigger picture' here... On the very same HTML page there is a form, and a div. Now right after a user fills out the form and submits it, it goes to the server and 'custom javascript' is generated depending on the variable the user selected. This custom javascript is then intended to go back to the client and execute. When it executes is creates/fills up a div element that then contains a google charts table (thus needed to get generated server side). The JS that needs to be executed looks like this:

```
var sendAttemptsChartTableData, sendAttemptsChartTable; 
google.load('visualization', '1', {packages:['table']}) 
 google.setOnLoadCallback(drawTable); 
 function drawTable() { 
sendAttemptsChartTableData = new google.visualization.DataTable();  
sendAttemptsChartTableData.addColumn('string','smsGuid')  
sendAttemptsChartTableData.addColumn('string','attemptNo')  
sendAttemptsChartTableData.addColumn('string','response')  
sendAttemptsChartTableData.addColumn('string','error')  
sendAttemptsChartTableData.addRows(1)  
sendAttemptsChartTableData.setCell(0,0,'092A49AA-E2EF-46D3-A83E-0932B17B649A')  
sendAttemptsChartTableData.setCell(0,1,'1')  
sendAttemptsChartTableData.setCell(0,2,'<aatsms><submitresult action="enqueued"     key="2066317199" result="1" number="0833756610"/><submitresult action="enqueued" key="2066317200" result="1" number="0833756610"/><submitresult action="enqueued" key="2066317201" result="1" number="0833756610"/><submitresult action="enqueued" key="2066317202" result="1" number="0833756610"/></aatsms>')  
sendAttemptsChartTableData.setCell(0,3,'')  
sendAttemptsChartTable = new  google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('sendAttemptsTable')); 
var view = new google.visualization.DataView(sendAttemptsChartTableData);   
sendAttemptsChartTable.draw(view, {showRowNumber: true, allowHtml:false}); 
google.visualization.events.addListener(sendAttemptsChartTable, 'select', smsSearchHandler); 
}
```

Comment: Why don't just create the required variable ?

Comment: This looks nasty. Believe me, you don't wanna do this. Take a step back and rethink what you're trying to do. `Eval`ing JS is generally a bad idea.

Comment: definitely not the right solution. this is very narrowly removed from `eval()`. If you can clarify what you're trying to accomplish, there's probably a very simple method for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your edit I understand your form sumbission results in a custom script. Would a `JSONP`-like solution work? Basically you can create a script tag in your current document, pointing its source to a server side script that processes the form and returns the code.

A basic example:

```
function getScript(){
  /**process form, generate params**/
  var nwScript = document.createElement('script');
  nwScript.src = '/myscriptsrc/somescript.php?'+[generated parameters];
  document.body.appendChild(nwScript);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is to execute the javascript code contained in the string, you can use the following :

```
var myVariable = "alert('BAM! It works!');";
eval(myVariable);
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip Oliver, that is pretty much exactly what I want to do.. Have a look at the edit to see exactly what I want to get done.

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do is essentially this:

```
var myVariable = "alert('BAM! It works!');";
eval(myVariable);
```

`eval` takes the string you provide and "evaluates" the content - it executes the javascript stuff you provide in the string. Normally you want to do this with input from the user.

But this is considered bad habit, because:

1. it is slow
2. it is unsecure

Usually you can go another way, so you don't need to use `eval`. In most cases this is cleaner, faster and more secure.

Perhaps you could tell, WHAT you are trying to achieve, and then we can find a better solution.

Comment: @DeanGrobler hey Dean, take a look at KooiInc's Answer, this should be a good solution. I would do something similar, so I won't edit my answer and just point out his solution.